# Can an installation profile have service.yml files?

Tags: installation-profiles, 10

I have a *dxp_installer* installation profile.
I want to use the container injection for a service which I use in `hook_install_tasks_alter()` to verify the installation requirements. Note that I inject this service in one of my custom install forms construct, and not directly from the *dxp_installer.install* file.

I have defined this service in the *dxp_installer.services.yml* file. Now when I  add `container->get('dxp_installer.service')`, I get an error about calling a non-existent service. Note that Drupal isn't installed yet at this stage. Are service files only usable after Drupal is installed?

Meanwhile, the actual service class is accessible with `$service = new InstallerService()`, which means the class is reachable by the class loader.

Comment: Can you confirm that hook name? Drupal doesn't seem to have a hook_install_alter.

This is the standard reminder that Drupal 8 reached end-of-life on November 2, 2021 and has known security bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Cilefen. I meant to write ```hook_install_tasks_alter```. I have made the correction in the original question. I'm also actually running this on Drupal 10, I've also updated the tags. So then are ```service.yml``` files allowed in Installation Profiles?

Comment: It's so early in the process you may have the minimal container. What services are in the container at that stage?

Comment: This isn't even a Drupal-defined service that I'm trying to access here. I'm trying to access a custom service which I defined in my profile's service.yml file. The question rather should be whether that service.yml file is processed at all - at that early stage?

Comment: Seems like I have to look for another way to reach my service then. Just wished container injection was available - it's a cleaner approach.

Comment: What services are in the container at that stage?